# How to check validity of header file in C programming language

Tags: c, file, header

Is there a way in C programming language to check if function prototypes from a header files corresponds to actual function definition in compile time. 
For example, if I made header file, and then change signature of some function described in that header file, can I check in compile time if there is a wrong prototype in header file? Is that a job of the compiler or some other tool before compilation?
Thanks.

Comment: Are your functions in other sources you compile or in libraries? If you're compiling them yourself here then you should get errors when you compile the function definition with a different signature.

Comment: If functions are in some library, and source code is already compiled. So, I have header file with wrong function signature and already compiled source file of that function. When I compile other source file which includes that header file, will compiler complain?

Comment: At compile time: no - the compiler will trust the header file is correct for your new code. You might get an error at link time for some cases depending on your system, e.g. on Windows if you're using __stdcall calling convention then the number of bytes of arguments is included in the generated symbol (e.g. _strcpy@8) so if the number of arguments in your signatures has changed then you'll get a linker error.

Comment: Thank you on your answer, so basically, to check if header file function signatures are the same as actual signatures in the source code file, compiler has to have that source code available at compile time in order to compare it to the header file.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the same function name with two different prototypes, the compiler should catch this, i.e.:

```
int foo(int a, int b);

...

int foo(int a, float b) { ... }
```

Of course, if you actually rename the function, then the compiler cannot catch it, i.e.:

```
int foo(int a, int b);

...

int fee(int a, int b) { ... }
```

Unless, of course, you attempt to call `foo` from elsewhere.  Then the linker will complain.

Comment: If I have prototype int foo(int a, int b); and implementation of that function is int foo(int a, float b) { ... }, e.g wrong. And when I compile some source code which includes this header file, and if in that moment compiler has only source code that includes header file and header file alone, without source code of header file functions implementation, can it then catch the error?

Comment: @Vladimir: The compiler should give you an error that says "conflicting types for 'foo'" (or something like that) when you compile the source file with the implementation of `foo`.  It won't give you a warning for any other source file.  But if you've changed the header file, your build system should attempt to recompile the implementation source file as well!

Comment: So, when I compile the other source file that doesn't contain implementation of foo, but it just includes header file with a wrong signature of foo compiler will not give any warning. But it has automatic mechanism to check header file and implementation file for the differences in function prototypes?

Comment: @Vladimir: That's correct.  But like I said, your build system should deal with this for you.

Answer (score 1):

That is the job of the compiler and in my experience it does it quite well:)

If your function prototype in header file does not match it's definition in the source file, then you cannot use that function in other source file because it is not declared and the compiler will inform you so, by giving an error.

Comment: If in time of compilation of some source file that includes some header file which source code file is not available in the time of compilation, should compiler complain?

Comment: @Vladimir Radojicic: If a source file includes a header file which is not present then the compiler will give the error that it cannot find the specific header file.

Comment: I meant source code of the implementation of some function in a header file is not present, not header file itself.

Comment: @Vladimir Radojicic: That will lead to a compilation but since the function definition does not exist, it will give you a linking error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function, the compiler will give you a linker error, if an implementation for a prototype does not exists. But if you never use the function (for example when you build a library) the linker will not complain.

This is one of the reasons you should make sure you have good code coverage in your tests - if you have for example some unit tests which also gets compiled, the linker will complain. If you have some functions you can not test and will not get called from within your code, you can just write a dummy executable (which does not have to work) which will call all this functions.

The last solution would be to use the clang libraries to write your own code checkers.