# C++ name mangling in C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, name-mangling

C language does not use name mangling like C++. This can lead to subtle bugs, when function prototype is declared differently in different files. Simple example:

```
/* file1.c */
int test(int x, int y)
{
    return y;
}

/* file2.c */
#include <stdio.h>

extern int test(int x);

int main()
{
    int n = test(2);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling such code using C compiler (in my case gcc) no errors are reported. After switching to C++ compiler, linking will fail with error "undefined reference to 'test(int)'". Unfortunately in practice this is not so easy - there are cases when code is accepted by C compiler (with possible warning messages), but compilation fails when using C++ compiler.

This is of course bad coding practice - all function prototypes should be added to .h file, which is then included in files where function is implemented or used. Unfortunately in my app there are many cases like this, and fixing all of them is not possible in short term. Switching to g++ is also not at option, I got compilation error quite fast.

One of possible solutions would be to use C++ name mangling when compiling C code. Unfortunately gcc does not allow to do this - I did not found command line option to do this. Do you know if it is possible to do this (maybe use other compiler?). I also wonder if some static analysis tools are able to catch this.

Comment: Simply compile all code as C++ and be done with it?

Comment: Program in C or program in C++. They are very different languages, don't try to use them as if they where the same

Comment: or put the header in an `extern "C"{} block` so that it knows not to look for a mangled version

Comment: @DarkFalcon: this is not so easy, I already tried this. Because of differences between C and C++ compilation fails, and it looks for me that fixing everything to compile in C++ mode would require a lot of work. Therefore I am looking for other solutions.

Comment: Technically, name-mangling isn't a part of C++.  It's an implmentation detail some vendors choose to use.  If they can handle function overloading across translation units in a different way, they are free to use that.

Comment: Am I missing something or is this not really a problem with name mangling?  Are you really OK with the C linker linking your 1-argument function call to the 2-argument function?  Especially since that function is returning the uninitialized arg?  That seems all sorts of messed up to me.

Comment: @indiv He wants the C compiler to refuse to link it. One possible way to do it would be to mangle the names.

Comment: @T.C.:  Ahhh thanks!  I see I understood the problem but not the question.

Comment: I guess, a tool like *lint* may diagnose the problem.

Comment: So this isn't really a C++ question? You want to prevent C code that calls a function with incorrect argument types or the wrong number of arguments from linking?

Comment: I guess, the thing that needs to be done is to hunt down all function declarations within .c files, and to move them to header files if they are not for recursive static functions. Because each forward declaration that the compiler never checks against the definition is either a bug or waiting to become one. `grep` is your friend...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137702/function-prototype-in-header-file-doesnt-match-definition-how-to-catch-this

Comment: This is actually up to the compiler.  MSVC, for example, does mangle C names.

Comment: @MobyDisk, that's nitpicking. Of course, adding an '_' is technically mangling. But what OP needs is not every kind of mangling but such kinds of mangling which produce different result for different prototypes.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Actually, MSVC puts the number of bytes in the argument list into the function name, for this very reason.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx

Comment: @MobyDisk Only if you use `__stdcall` (or `__fastcall`) *and* are compiling for 32-bit systems.

Comment: @MobyDisk, in a large project it's next to impossible to enforce __stdcall on all functions. And even then it only differentiates by size.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy There is a [compiler switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx) that makes all functions not explicitly declared otherwise `__stdcall`.

Comment: @T.C., yes, certainly. But real-world project also have dependencies, and it may (rather than may not) be problematic to make them link thus.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`splint`](http://splint.org/) catches these kinds of errors.

foo.c:

```
int test(int x);
int main() {
    test(0);
}
```

bar.c:

```
int test(int x, int y) {
    return y;
}
```

Running `splint`:

```
$ splint -weak foo.c bar.c
Splint 3.1.2 --- 20 Feb 2009

bar.c:1:5: Function test redeclared with 2 args, previously declared with 1
  Types are incompatible. (Use -type to inhibit warning)
   foo.c:4:5: Previous declaration of test

Finished checking --- 1 code warning
```

Comment: At first look splint looks nice. However I am afraid I will not be able to use it - I have huge code base, with multiple modules compiled to intermediate libraries (each one with custom compilation options) and later linked into final app. I checked split manual and at at first sight there are no options corresponding to `-c` and `-o` in gcc.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I was more or less answering the static analysis part of your question; `splint` isn't a compiler itself so you would compile as usual with GCC, after getting a successful result (i.e., no errors) from `splint`.

Answer (score 0):

```
~/dev/temp$ cat > a.c
int f(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

~/dev/temp$ cat > b.c
extern int f(int x); int g(int x) { return f(x + x); }

~/dev/temp$ splint *.c
Splint 3.1.2 --- 03 May 2009

b.c:1:12: Function f redeclared with 1 arg, previously declared with 2
  Types are incompatible. (Use -type to inhibit warning)
   a.c:1:5: Previous declaration of f

Finished checking --- 1 code warning
~/dev/temp$
```